# What is the most proper way to close a websocket

Tags: c#, .net-core, clientwebsocket

In my .NET Core console app I use collection of ClientWebSocket objects to receive some data. When something goes wrong and an exception occurs I'd like to close all websockets.

I tried to do this in such way:

```
foreach (var socket in _sockets)
{
    if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open || socket.State == WebSocketState.Connecting)
    {
        socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
    }
}
```

But in case of `socket.State == WebSocketState.Connecting` there is an exception:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The WebSocket is in an invalid state ('Connecting') for this operation. Valid states are: 'Open, CloseReceived, CloseSent')'

I know that I can use `socket.Abort()` for `WebSocketState.Connecting` as well as for `WebSocketState.Open`.

The question is whether it will be the most proper way to close the connections - by using `CloseAsync` for `WebSocketState.Open` and `Abort` for `WebSocketState.Connecting`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you cannot close something that is not opened. The methods `SendAsync`, `ReceiveAsync`, `CloseAsync`, `CloseOutputAsync` always check the state of socket before taking any other action. If the state is not "connected", they throw exception.

The following states are considered as "not connected":

- `WebSocketState.None`
- `WebSocketState.Connecting`
- `WebSocketState.Closed`

We can add `WebSocketState.Aborted` to the list as well.

Taking into account this fact, if you are not waiting a close request or sending one, you can close your sockets as simple as follows:

```
foreach (var socket in _sockets)
{
    if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
    {
        await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

I don't have the visibility of the remaining parts of your code. Therefore, I assume you try to run the `CloseAsync` method synchronously. I recommend that you think twice before using `Wait()` in async code. You literally block the current thread and waiting for the `Task` to complete. Do you really need this? You should use `async` all the way down as much as possible. Otherwise, you may end up deadlock in async code easily.